# Creating Snap Shot of Windows Forms And Opened Documents

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, pixel, system.drawing

I am working with creating snap shots of Windows Form and User Controls to PDF documents, The Issue I am facing is the quality they produce, for larger fonts its pretty fine and minor change is ignorable, but for smaller Fonts size controls , there is clearly seen that it is not proper representation of data.

I was using below mechanism in vb.net .

```
Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
```

By searching I have found another extra parameter that may support different formats or color schemes, that is below

```
Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap= New Bitmap(CInt(Width), CInt(Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
```

I didn't find any improved image quality, any body there can share the best optimal quality for black & white printing.?

Here is Edit:

```
 bmpScreenshot = New Bitmap(CInt(PageWidth), CInt(PageHeight), PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb) '.Format32bppArgb
        ''make image for bmpScreenshot
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
        Dim isPage As Boolean = MyDataGridViewPrinter.DrawDataGridView(g, PrintE)
```

Comment: How are you acquiring the image? `BitBlt`?

Comment: I have added updated lines.

Answer (score 0):

Things on screen looks sharper than on paper. The number of dots per inch is multiple times higher on paper than on a standard computer screen. Therefore, you should make your BMP much larger in size (for example if you want 300 dpi and your document is 10x20 inch, your BMP should be 3000x6000 pixels).

Next, increase all dimensions for your controls, including row heights, font sizes, border sizes, ... Multiply them all by 4 for example.

And of course you should use 24 (or 32) bits per pixel and make sure anti-aliasing is enabled.

Comment: I have large number of forms and controls < making them large is not required, is there any way that with same dimension, I create a larger density image and print on it?

Comment: Oke, i misunderstood and thought your destination was for PDF documents. But maybe the same trick will work to render a larger image first and then scale it down assuming the scaler will do a better job then the control renderer.